# Seeking the Maximum of a Product expression using Inequalities

Tags: inequality, optimization, maxima-minima, products, buffalo-way

Since $\ln a\leq a-1,$ I tried to use that inequality to calculate a maximum value for
$$\prod_{cyc}\frac{9y+4z-6x}{x}$$
where $x,y,z>0$. Or
$$\sum_{cyc}\log\frac{9y+4z-6x}{x}$$
Then
$$\log\frac{9y+4z-6x}{x}\leq\frac{9y+4z-7x}{x}$$
but it seems not to go further.

Comment: What if, for example, $\frac{9y+4z-6x}{x}<0$ ?

Comment: it is a good question

Comment: i gave +1, thank you

Comment: @Steven Also, I have a solution by uvw, but it's complicated enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x=y=z$ we get a value $343$.

We'll prove that it's a maximal value.

Indeed, we need to prove that
$$\prod_{cyc}\frac{9y+4z-6x}{x}\leq343$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(36x^3-92x^2y+33x^2z+23xyz)\geq0.$$
Now, let $x=\min\{x,y,z\}$, $y=x+u$ and $z=x+v$.

Thus, we need to prove that
$$49(u^2-uv+v^2)x+(9u+4v)(2u-3v)^2\geq0,$$ which is obvious.

Done!